# Initiate UITableView Drag Programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I have iOS 11 drag and drop setup on my `UITableView` and can freely reorder my cells as I please using `UITableViewDragDelegate` & `UITableViewDropDelegate`.

I want to initiate a drag of multiple cells/objects upon holding a section header in my table. Is it possible?